# Executing Commands In Parallel That Never Finish

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script

I'm attempting to run a few commands that never finish.  These commands watch a directory and update files when they change.  The idea is that I need multiple folders watched by different tools, able to run all of them from a single command.

For normal commands that return as expected, separating the commands with a `;` works.

```
ls /;
cd /;
ls var;
cd var;
ls log;
cd log
```

When I attempt to chain together non-returning commands (like `tail -f <some_file>` or `coffee -c -w <some_coffeescript_folder>`, only the first command will run.

Is there a way of doing this in a single command?  Here's the commands I'm trying to link together:

```
coffee -c -m -w public/javascript/*.coffee; \
stylus views/stylesheets/*.styl -w -m --out public/stylesheets/; \
stylus views/stylesheets/lib/*.styl -w -m --out public/stylesheets/lib/;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "one after another" if the first one never finishes? When do you want the second one to start?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The first one won't finish.  I just want all of them to run.  I suppose sequentially isn't actually true here, parallel would be more accurate. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run them in background by adding an ampersand to the command:

```
coffee -c -m -w public/javascript/*.coffee &
stylus views/stylesheets/*.styl -w -m --out public/stylesheets/ &
stylus views/stylesheets/lib/*.styl -w -m --out public/stylesheets/lib/ &
```

If you want to see all jobs currently running in the background do a:

```
jobs -l
```

To get a background job back into foreground, use fg (PID is optional):

```
fg <PID>
```

To send a foreground job (which "blocks" your shell) back into background mode use Ctrl-Z / bg:

```
$ tail -f foobar.log # is "blocking" your shell
(hit Ctrl-Z)
$ bg
```

I guess the jobs are bound to your shell and will not fork automatically.
This means if you're logged in via SSH and you disconnect, the shell receives a SIGHUP, which will be sent to the jobs as well. This will stop/exit your commands.

If you want to keep the jobs up&running even after you've logged out, you might want look into the bash built-in "disown":

```
jobs               # fetch job ID in the squre brackets
disown -h %<JOBID> # disown job by using the job ID
```

Another option is "nohup" (command, not a bash built-in) or you use a terminal multiplexer like "screen" or "tmux".

Comment: [Holy...](http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2011/288/5/b/mother_of_god_by_rober_raik-d4cw2di.png)  Great answer, thanks a ton!  I'm actually setting these commands up in a horribly butchered Makefile, but there's a lot of info I didn't know about here.  Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Comment: btw if you want to "watch" a directory or file, have a look into inotify and the command-line inotify-tools https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
coffee -c -m -w public/javascript/*.coffee &
stylus views/stylesheets/*.styl -w -m --out public/stylesheets/ &
stylus views/stylesheets/lib/*.styl -w -m --out public/stylesheets/lib/ &
```

Comment: I actually tried this, but I had an extra `;` after the ampersand.  Thanks!